# How to adjust pathname according to iframe path?

Tags: php, jquery, html, iframe

I am looking for a way to adjust the path of my url according to the path inside an iframe on that site.

Basically I am using an iframe to show a shop on one my store.domain.com sub-domain and I want the path of the iframe and the path of the site to be the same. Say you enter **`store.domain.com/men/t-shirts/tshirt1.php`** or something it would automatically change the src of the iframe to **`domain.spreadshirt.com/men/t-shirts/tshirt1.php`**

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

You want to set the current page URL as iframe SRC? If so, try this code `<iframe src = "<?php echo '//' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; ?>" width = "640" height = "360" />` in your PHP file.